# Don't take into account a background to compute the area of an item

Tags: android, background, imageview

My problem is the following:

I have an `ImageView` with a background. The background is a drawable that paints different images depending on the state.

*context_menu_button.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_focused" 
    android:state_focused="true"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_focused" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>

<!-- Normal -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

Then I have a `star icon` with this `context_menu_button` applied as background:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnStar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/context_menu_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_star"  />
```

The image `button_round_focused` is actually very big, because it's an image with a very subtle gradient. There's no image (transparent color) in normal state. This is how the XML above looks like (focused state):

[image: Star icon]

The size of this background is causing me some trouble. When painting the star icon, the background is taken into account to compute the area of the icon star. So,  when I align two or more icons similar to this one, they got very distant from each other.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnStar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/context_menu_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_star" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnShare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/context_menu_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_share" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnRate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/context_menu_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_rate" />
```

[image: star-share-rate]

My solution was to set left negative margins, so they got closed together.

[image: star-share-rate-with-negative-margins]

However, this solution caused another problem. Now the items are overlapped:

[image: star-overlapped]

[image: share-overlapped]

[image: rate-overlapped]

Now, for instance, when I try to click on item share (button in the middle) it's actually the third button that gets clicked, because they are overlapped.

My ideal solution would be that the background applied to an `ImageView` were not taken into account to calculate the area of the item it's applied to. Something like this:

[image: star-with-background-out-of-bounds]

In other words, the background could go out of the area of the `ImageView`.

I think that could solve the problem, but I've been reading the docs and I couldn't find anything related to this. Any other ideas would be appreciated (although changing the size of the bakground is not possible).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this issue. What I did was the following:

1) Removed the background from the buttons.

The backgrounds were the root reason of this problem. Without backgrounds, everything was working as expected.

2) Managed programatically showing up the background behind and icon when it gets focused or when it's clicked.

In order to do this, the first thing I did was to change the layout. I put all the icons (star, share, rate) within a `FrameLayout`. I also appended an ImageView with the drawable button_round_focused (the halo showed above). The idea is to move this image to the right icon when an icon gets focused. As the image is located before the icons, its *Z-index* is lower, so it'll be painted behind the icons.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_round_focused"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button_round_focused"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Favorite button -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnFav"
            style="@style/MediaDetailsStarButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/star" />

        <!-- Share button -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
            style="@style/MediaDetailsShareButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/share" />

        <!-- Rate button -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnRate"
            style="@style/MediaDetailsRateButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/to_rate" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

After redefining the layout, I programmed the logic of moving the halo to the right position when necessary. Moving it when an icon gets focused was relatively easy. I attached an `OnFocusChangeListener` to every icon like this:

```
icon.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            btnRoundFocused.setX(center(v));
            btnRoundFocused.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnRoundFocused.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

The method `center()` calculates the right X coord for `btnRoundFocused`, so both icon and background get centered.

```
private float center(View v) {
    int middle = btnRoundFocused.getWidth() / 2;
    return v.getX() + (v.getWidth() / 2) - middle;
}
```

Then, I did the same when an icon got clicked. This was more difficult. What I had to do was: when an icons gets clicked, show the background for a while and then hide it.

```
private void withButtonPressed(View v, IButtonAction action) {
    buttonPressed(v);
    action.execute(v);
    buttonUnpressed(v);
}

protected void buttonPressed(View v) {
    btnRoundFocused.setX(center(v));
    btnRoundFocused.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.setActivated(true);
}

protected void buttonUnpressed(final View v) {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        private final int ELLAPSE_TIME = 250;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(ELLAPSE_TIME);
                v.setActivated(false);
                btnRoundFocused.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

interface IButtonAction {
    void execute(View v);
}
```

I defined a method `withButtonPressed()` that receives an `IButtonAction`. `IButtonAction` implements the business logic of the correspondent icon (star, share, rate). withButtonPressed() sets the background at the right position, shows the background for a while (250 milliseconds), and hides it again.

Finally I also had to add a new state, activated, in the drawable of an icon (*icon_share.xml*, for instance). An icon is a XML with several drawables depending on its state (icon in black color when it's focused or clicked, icon in gray color in normal state).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Activated -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_share_focused"
        android:state_activated="true"/>

    <!-- Focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_share_focused" 
        android:state_focused="true"/>

    <!-- Normal -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_share"/>

</selector>
```

And that was it. I don't know if there's a better way to solve this issue, but at least this worked. Hope it can be helpful to other people facing similar problems.